# Convert String to int in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
string title = "title1";
```

If I want to make it `title2` how can I?

as I cant convert whole as int, may something like cropping or trimming ?

*title suffix(1) is not a fixed number*

just I want to alter the last digit which always be a int

Comment: `title = title.replace('1', '2');`

Comment: `title = title.slice(0,-1) + 2;`

Comment: if title1's '1' is unknown number then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number can be more than one char, the answer using splice will not work.

So it's best to first get the number and increment it:

```
var title = "title1";
var i = title.substr(5);
console.log("title" + ++i);
```

**Output**

```
title2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
title = title.slice(0,-1) + (+title.replace(/\D/g, '') + 1);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MMa7H/)

or

```
title = title.slice(0,-1) + (+title.slice(-1) + 1);
```

or

```
title = title.replace(/\d+/g, function(x) {return ++x});
```

Comment: `return (+x)+1` can be written as `return ++x`

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yes it can, and \d+ would match numbers higher than 9

Answer (score -1):

```
title = title.slice(0,(title.indexOf('e')+1)-title.length) + '2';
```

This will remove all characters after the letter 'e' in title and add the number at the end

Answer (score -1):

This answer solved my Problem,
the most dynamic way to do so...

```
var title = "title1";
var i = title.substr(5);
var newTitle = ("title" + ++i);
```